# c sizeof() leads to overflow?

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char *p ;
    char *q ;
    char *l = "aaaaaasdfsfdqwecvxcxfwdsagfd" ;
    p = (char*)malloc(sizeof(l)) ;
    q = (char*)malloc(strlen(l)) ;
    strcpy(p, l) ;
    strcpy(q, l) ;
    printf("%s\n",p) ;
    printf("%s\n",q) ;
    printf("%d\n",strlen(l)) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

please look at this, when input some characters within 23 characters, it's OK, while inputting characters more than 23, like images shows that, my result displays with messy code, why that happened ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWJP7.png)

Comment: don't post code as images, it's horrible. and you're not allocating enough mem, missing null-termination char. probably the problem, but now I have to get eye surgery so you'll excuse me.

Comment: i'm sorry..it's my first time to ask question on stackoverflow, i will fix it. Thanks.    I don't think addin null-termination char works here, it already exists

Answer (score 3):

When you do `sizeof` on a pointer, you get the size of the pointer and not the memory it points to. This will typically be either 4 or 8 depending on if you're on a 32 or 64 bit system.

Then `strlen` returns the length of the string *without* the null terminator.

Both of these sizes are to small to hold the full string with the terminator, leading to *undefined behavior* when the `strcpy` calls go out of bounds.

Comment: I understood !   Thanks.

Comment: But I still have a problem ,  when I do sizeof on the pointer, I get a 4 byte mem, whereas, the string I input is more than 4 characters ,actually it got 23 byte,so why I could get more than 4 correct characters output ?

Comment: @LiuYikai To get the correct length of a string you should use `strlen`. To get the length of a string *including* the terminator, you add one to the length that `strlen` returns (i.e. `strlen(l) + 1` in your example)

Comment: I mean, use "sizeof" to allocate 4 byte to store 4 characters, here the space store 23 characters(bytes) ,which are more than 4 bytes ,is that correct ?